# How can I use Socket IO to send push notifications in my Express server with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, push-notification

How do I implement socket io for push notification in my express server using typescript ?
I have basic server and a controller that receives message from one user and when there is a message submitted by the user I want to sent a push notification to the user for whom the message is sent using Socket Io .

```
import { Server as SocketIOServer, Socket } from 'socket.io';

const push_Response_Notification = (io: SocketIOServer) => {
    return (socket: Socket, next: (err?: Error) => void) => {
      socket.on('response-generated', (data: { userId: string, message: string }) => {
        const { userId, message } = data;
    
        // Emit the notification message to the specific user identified by userId
        io.to(userId).emit('notification', { message });
      });

      next();
    };
  };

export default push_Response_Notification;
```

This is a basic push notification middleware i have tried.